# remove unwanted characters from all cells within a column in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code to remove characters except A-Z, a-z or 0-9 from A1 cell to G1 cell. How could I iterate for a whole A:A into G:G? The code I have only works for only a cell. I want to do all cells within a column. Please kindly help.

```
   Sub test()     
       Dim a$, b$, c$, k As Integer

       a$ = Range("A1").Value
       For i = 1 To Len(a$)
           b$ = Mid(a$, i, 1)
           If b$ Like "[A-Z,a-z,0-9]" Then
               c$ = c$ & b$
       End If
       Next i
       Range("G1").Value = c$     
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse your loop or a version of a loop to loop through the cells.

There may be a better way than this, but it should work

```
Sub Test()
Dim a$, b$, c$, k As Integer, LastR#, x As Long

LastR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To LastR
    a = Range("A" & x).Value
    c = ""
    For I = 1 To Len(a$)
        b = Mid(a$, I, 1)
        If b$ Like "[A-Z,a-z,0-9]" Then
            c = c & b
        End If
    Next I
    Range("G" & x).Value = c
Next x
End Sub
```